# Counting distinct fields in Apache Spark for Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

Data set:

[image: DataSet]

For the above data set I want to count the number of different entries in the fourth column. I have code in Python but not able to implement it in Java using Spark.

Python code:

```
user_data = sc.textFile(dataSet path)

//counting number of occupations
num_occupations = user_fields.map(lambda fields:
fields[3]).distinct().count()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupBy and count:

```
num_occupations = user_fields.groupBy("name_of_your_column").count()
```

Reference:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/index.html#package

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/RelationalGroupedDataset.html

Answer (score 0):

```
val df = sc.parallelize(
Seq(
  (892,36,"M","other","45243"),
  (893,25,"M","student","95823"),
  (894,47,"M","education","74075"),
  (895,31,"F","librarian","74075"),
  (896,28,"M","writer","91505"),
  (897,30,"M","hommaker","61755")
  )
  ).toDF("a","b","c","d","e")


val df2 = df.groupBy("d").agg(collect_set("a")).show()
```

Resuts :

```
scala> val df = sc.parallelize(
     | Seq(
     |   (892,36,"M","other","45243"),
     |   (893,25,"M","student","95823"),
     |   (894,47,"M","education","74075"),
     |   (895,31,"F","librarian","74075"),
     |   (896,28,"M","writer","91505"),
     |   (897,30,"M","hommaker","61755")
     |   )
     |   ).toDF("a","b","c","d","e");
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: int ... 3 more fields]

scala> val df2 = df.groupBy("d").agg(collect_set("a")).show()
+---------+--------------+
|        d|collect_set(a)|
+---------+--------------+
|librarian|         [895]|
| hommaker|         [897]|
|education|         [894]|
|   writer|         [896]|
|    other|         [892]|
|  student|         [893]|
+---------+--------------+
```